# Can a custom grid be populated with custom data in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, grid, query

I've created a Magento 2 extension containing two custom grids. The first reads directly from a custom table in the database. I want the second to display data retrieved with a specific query using other tables. Is this possible?

Can a custom grid be populated with data from a query instead of reading data from it's "mainTable?"

Comment: Do you use UI grid or normal grid?

Comment: @PrincePatel, I guess I'm not sure. I didn't know there were different types of grids in Magento 2. I'm trying to create a grid just like the product grid, except it will be populated with data from other tables.